# Proving that the limit at $(0,-1)$ does not exist

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

I have the following function:

$$f(x,y) =\begin{cases} \frac {x^4 + (y+1)^3}{x^2 + (y+1)^2} &\text{ if }(x,y) \neq (0,-1)\\ 0 &\text{  if }(x,y) = (0,-1)\end{cases}$$

> Prove that the limit of $f$ at $(0,-1)$ does not exists

I have been trying to prove this limit does not exist by composing $f(\alpha (t)) $ using different curves $\alpha (t)$ but I can't seem to find any that can prove it. Polynomials and circles don't seem to work. What else could I try?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, the limit seems to exist:

$$ 0 \leq |f(x,y)| = \left|\dfrac{x^4}{x^2+(y+1)^2} + \dfrac{(y+1)^3}{x^2+(y+1)^2}\right|  \leq x^2 + |(y+1)|$$

The right hand side goes to $0$ in the limit.

Comment: How did you get that inequality?

Comment: It was an application of the [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality).

Comment: Thanks! I was certain the limit should not exist for some reason

Answer (score 4):

Note that wlog by a change of coordinates we can study $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ and by polar coordinates

$$\frac {x^4 +y^3}{x^2 + y^2}=r\cdot f(r,\theta)\to 0$$

since $f(r,\theta)=r\cos^4 \theta+\sin^3 \theta$ is bounded.

Comment: I have no idea how this works, sorry.

Comment: @FranciscoJoséLetterio you have no idea about what? it is a standard way to solve limits of several variable. If you need some esplanation do not hesitate to ask. Bye

Comment: @gimusi why can we look at $x^4+y^3$ and not $x^4+(y+1)^3$?

Comment: @gbox I've assumed a change of coordinates x'=x and y'=y+1.

Comment: @gimusi I know that such a step can be done to find the form of a comic section. Why can we use it for finding limits?

Comment: @gbox we can always change reference system in this way I can consider the limit at (0,0) which is simpler to handle and by polar coordinates it becomes trivial.